# Trying to get calculation to work and change function on different option?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to coding and i'm struggling to get this calculation to work. Not sure what i'm doing wrong. I'm also wondering how to change the function when the select option is changed? The aim is to get function calculate() to work when option value is '0' and function calculate2() when the value is '1' . Any help greatly appreciated.

https://jsfiddle.net/8r5d0boc/3/

```
<select id ="option">
 <option value="0">Quali</option>
 <option value="1">Free</option>
</select>

<input id="bstake" type="number" onInput="calculate()">
<input id="display" type="number" readonly>
<button id="calc" onClick="calculate()">Calculate</button>
```

Here's the script

```
function calculate()
{
    var backstake = document.getElementById('bstake').value;
    var result1 = document.getElementById('display');
        var myResult1 = (10-backstake);
        result1.value = myResult1;
}
function calculate2()
{
        var backstake = document.getElementById('bstake').value;
        var result2 = document.getElementById('display');
    var myResult1 = (50-backstake);
    result1.value = myResult1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to set a function to be called when the select changes, passing the select as an argument to the function.

```js
function calculate() {
  var backstake = document.getElementById('bstake').value;
  var result1 = document.getElementById('display');
  var myResult1 = (10-backstake);
  result1.value = myResult1;
}

function calculate2() {
  var backstake = document.getElementById('bstake').value;
  var result2 = document.getElementById('display');
  var myResult1 = (50-backstake);
  result2.value = myResult1;
}

function checkOptions(select) {
  if (select.options[select.selectedIndex].value == 0)
    calculate();
  else if (select.options[select.selectedIndex].value == 1)
    calculate2();
}
```

```html
<select id="option" onchange="checkOptions(this)">
 <option value="0">Quali</option>
 <option value="1">Free</option>
</select>

<input id="bstake" type="number" onInput="calculate()">
<input id="display" type="number" readonly>
<button id="calc" onClick="calculate()">Calculate</button>
```

Comment: Why add an extra function instead of eliminating the nearly duplicate functions?

Comment: Thanks for the help. Should have said in the question, this is just a trial for a much bigger and different calculation. But thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

The two functions are just about identical, so let's not write two versions of essentially the same thing. Instead, we can have one function that accepts a parameter as input and based on that input, the function will respond in one of two ways.

Secondly, it's best not to hook up your HTML elements to JavaScript event handlers via HTML attributes. This creates "spaghetti code" that is difficult to read and maintain. But, it also creates anonymous global wrapper functions to hold your attribute value. Instead, do all the event wiring in JavaScript.

```js
// Get DOM references:
var btn = document.getElementById("calc");
var list = document.getElementById("option");
var output = document.getElementById("display");
var backstake = document.getElementById("bstake");

// Wire up event handlers:
btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
   calculate(list.value);
});

backstake.addEventListener("input", function(){
   calculate(list.value);
});

// Event handler:
function calculate(input){
    if(input === "0"){
        myResult = 10-backstake.value;
    } else {
        myResult = 50-backstake.value;  
    }
  
    output.value = myResult;
}
```

```html
<select id ="option">
 <option value="0">Quali</option>
 <option value="1">Free</option>
</select>

<input id="bstake" type="number">
<input id="display" type="number" readonly>
<button id="calc">Calculate</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since both functions are almost identical and the only value being changed differently is `myResult1`, you'll only need to execute one function. Since you don't need to change the function, we only need to intelligently determine the value of `myResult1` depending if the value of the `<select/>` is either 0 or 1. There are several different methods for accomplishing this. Here I will demonstrate how to set the value of `myResult1` dynamically using a [conditional ("ternary") operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Conditional_(ternary)_operator):

```js
function calculate() {
  var option = document.getElementById('option').value;
  var backstake = document.getElementById('bstake').value;
  var result1 = document.getElementById('display');
  var myResult1 = (option == '0') ? (10 - backstake) : (50 - backstake);
  result1.value = myResult1;
}
```

```html
<select id="option">
 <option value="0">Quali</option>
 <option value="1">Free</option>
</select>

<input id="bstake" type="number" onInput="calculate()">
<input id="display" type="number" readonly>
<button id="calc" onClick="calculate()">Calculate</button>
```

Normally the HTML [event](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp) attributes are used to call functions specified elsewhere in script tags. In rare cases you may wish to add the JavaScript code directly to these `onClick` or `onMouseOver` event tags, but this is not considered good design. As `@scott-marcus` pointed out, you may want to go with a [JavaScript HTML DOM EventListener](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp):

```js
function calculate() {
  var option = document.getElementById('option').value;
  var backstake = document.getElementById('bstake').value;
  var result1 = document.getElementById('display');
  var myResult1 = (option == '0') ? (10 - backstake) : (50 - backstake);
  result1.value = myResult1;
}

document.getElementById('bstake').addEventListener('input', calculate);
document.getElementById('calc').addEventListener('click', calculate);
```

```html
<select id="option">
 <option value="0">Quali</option>
 <option value="1">Free</option>
</select>

<input id="bstake" type="number">
<input id="display" type="number" readonly>
<button id="calc">Calculate</button>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan How about them apples?